# Ajax jquery making web api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made an api in java , which allows the user to get data.
there is an call : ..../api/users where i give a list back of all users avalible.

Now i got a site with a search user button, wen you press that button i want to make a call to /api/users with the help of Ajax.

i got the part that you can click on the search button, but i don't understand how to make that call with ajax

This is my code:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: ”api / resource / users ",  
        dataType: "json”, 
    }

).fail(
    funcNon(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("APIRequestfailed: " + textStatus);
    }

).done(
    funcNon(data) {

        alert("succes!")

    }
);
```

Is this the way of making a good call with ajax ?
or do i have to use :

> http://localhost/projectUser/api/resource/users ?

Comment: write your ajax inside the click event handler.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I didn't understood the problem. You want to make an ajax call to your local server? The link that you've posted is for localhost - users online cannot use it (cause it's local for your machine)

Comment: @PavelDurov yes i want to make an ajax call to my localhost. because im new to this i try to start with local host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using JQuery to make the Ajax call then this sample code should be helpful to you. What it does is;

1. On search button was clicked
2. Do AJAX call to fetch stuff from your Java REST API
3. When the expected JSON object was returned, parse it and do something

O

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demoSearchBtn').click(function () {
        // Search button was clicked!
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",    
            url: "http://localhost/projectUser/api/resource/users",  // edit this URL to point into the URL of your API  
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);
                // Do something with your JSON return object
            },
            error: function (xhr) {  
                alert('oops something went wrong! Error:' + JSON.stringify(xhr));  
            }  
        }); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this `http://localhost/projectUser/api/resource/users` is the url, it's either

```
  $.ajax({
    url: ”api/resource/users",   ...
```

or

```
  $.ajax({
    url: ”http://localhost/projectUser/api/resource/users",  ...
```

depending on what the browsers current URL is (relative or absoute depends on context of the browser).

but it is *never ever* `”api / resource / users "` with spaces between words and slashes.

Comment: i already had api/resource/users , i don't know why its shown as api / resource / users here..